# Is there always a function (or formal power series) for the $n$th term of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let's imagine four types of sequences:

1. Finite, non-random sequences
2. Finite, random sequences
3. Infinite, non-random sequences
4. Infinite, random sequences

What do I mean by *random* here? It means that the sequence abides by no rules, other than that every term is a number. It does not mean that it is randomly generated, as a finite sequence may be randomly generated and accidentally abide by a set of rules, i.e. if the sequence $2,4,6$ was randomly generated.

I'm pretty sure that any finite sequence will always have function that gives the $n$th term, but this function can only be made and used as long as one knows what all the terms are, which kind of makes the function trivial.

The function that gives $n$th term in a finite sequence of an $x$-amount of terms is:

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k/n\rfloor \times a_k $$

($a_n$ and $a_k$ are the $n$th and $k$th terms of the sequence, respectively)

Now, this then means that any finite sequence has a function for its $n$th term. However, to access this function, one needs to know what every term is, thus making the function pretty useless. It exists however. With infinite sequences, it is impossible to know what every term is beforehand, thus making the above function useless. This means that infinite, random sequences have no generating function for their $n$th term.

So, these are my questions:

Is there always a generating function for any infinite, non-random sequence?

Is there always a function for any finite, non-random sequence, that can be found without knowing every term beforehand?

Comment: Firstly, your definition of "random" is not very precise and it is hard to know what you mean by it. Secondly, "generating function" does not seem to be the correct terminology, that term is usually reserved for something else. Thirdly, by "function" you seem to mean "closed form expression", because otherwise such a function trivially exists by sending each $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ to the $n$th term in the sequence.

Comment: If we interpret this as asking whether there is a "set of rules" or "function" generating a sequence that is sizably shorter than listing out all terms of the sequence, i.e. if the sequence is compressible, the answer is no, see [algorithmically random sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence).